# Is it possible to get the annotated element from an annotation instance?

Tags: java, annotations

If we have a class like this:

```
public class Foo {

  @MyAnnotation
  private String name;

}
```

And then have an instance of `Foo`:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
```

Using reflection, we can get a `Field` instance representing `name` and from there using `getAnnotation(MyAnnotation.class)` we can get the instance of the annotation that is applied to the that field.

My question is, is it possible to get the *annotated element* (i.e. field, method, type, etc.) from an annotation?

For example:

```
MyAnnotation anno = ...;
anno.getField(); // returns the `Field` object representing the `name` field of a particular instance of `Foo`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. :)

It appears to be a one way reference. I assume you want to pass the annotation to some other code which would then need to know what it was applied to? When you extract the annotations from the annotated element, you would store the field, method etc with the annotation at that time.  Perhaps create a wrapper bean which contains the Annotation and the annotated element.

Or, if the original class is available, get all annotations all compare them for equality, returning the element when there is a match. Not preferable, but possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Looks like it is really not possible. However in this case I am using a framework and it is not possible to customize it in such a way to get passed a reference to the annotated element along with the annotation itself.